# When should MRT (Multiple Render Targets) be used?

Tags: opengl, glsl, multiple-render-targets

I had a question about exactly when I should use the MRT. This is not about rendering models, but about post processing. For example, I need to draw some cubic textures (something like skybox rendering). And how much will drawing in one pass be faster than in several? And will it be faster?

**EDIT**: My shaders looks like this:

vertex:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPos;

out vec3 texCoords;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main() {
    vec4 pos = transform * vec4(inPos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pos.xyww;
    texCoords = inPos;
}
```

fragment:

```
#version 330 core

#define vecout vec3
#define OUT_COLOR_COMPONENT 0

in vec3 texCoords;

layout(location = OUT_COLOR_COMPONENT) out vecout fragColor;

uniform samplerCube cubemap;
uniform vecout color = vecout(1.0);

void main() {
    fragColor = vecout(texture(cubemap, texCoords)) * color;
}
```

Comment: StackExchange is generally better at answering "I have this particular problem, what is a solution for it?" rather than "I have this particular solution (MRT), what problems does it solve?" Can you tell us more about the cubemap feature you're developing, how you're approaching it so far, and where it's not yet working the way you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of MRT comes from the need to save bandwidth between multiple draw calls. Yes, it will be somewhat faster, but the difference depends on various factors such as how good your hardware is and how complex your rendering pipeline is.

A quick example of a good MRT usage is G-Buffer acquirement for deferred rendering. It is way more cheap to write to multiple buffers in one pass than calling different state resets/changes to fill them one by one.